# Firestore created document Eventarc audit log methods are inconsistent

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, event-arc

I am trying to call a service when a new Firestore document is created. With Cloud Functions v1 this was simple and worked great (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events). With Cloud Functions v2/Cloud Run being triggered via Eventarc, I'm struggling to get similar or even consistent behavior and feel like I'm missing something.

My expectation that would get us the same behavior as exists with v1 functions I would need to have an audit log recorded with a service name of `firestore.googleapis.com`  and a method name of `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.CreateDocument` (per https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#cloud-firestore) to be created. I'm getting audit logs written for document creation, but no consistent behavior.

1. If I create a new document in the GCP or Firebase Console, an audit log record with a service name of `firestore.googleapis.com` and method name of `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write` generated.
2. If I create a new document using the Firestore Client SDK (tested with Android), an audit log record with a service name of `firestore.googleapis.com` and method name of `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write` is generated.
3. If I create a new document using the Firestore Admin SDK (tested with both `"@google-cloud/firestore` and `firebase-admin` for Node and `cloud.google.com/go/firestore` for Go...all the same behavior), an audit log record with a service name of `firestore.googleapis.com` and method name of `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Commit` generated.

```
// JS implementation...similar implementation for Go
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
...
const db = new Firestore({...});
const collection = db.collection('users');
const res = await collection.add({});
```

4. If I create a new document using the Firestore REST API, an audit log record with a service name of `firestore.googleapis.com` and method name of `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.CreateDocument` generated.

```
curl --request \
    POST 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/users' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN' \
     --data '{"fields":{}}'
```

My goal is to have a behavior similar to v1 functions where I can reliably respond to document creation.

None of the above are necessarily wrong, but not having consistent behavior is not great. I don't feel like I'm doing something wrong, but clearly am not doing something right either. What is it that I'm missing or should I correct my Eventarc mental model?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want to achive? Do you want to have the same behavior of Cloud functions v1 to v2 with regards to the result in its method name? The v2 provides you more powerful infrastructure, advanced control over performance and scalability, and more control of the functions runtime, but it's still on Beta. I wouldn't recommend using it on production for now as it still can have improvements or changes along the way.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify my goal is to have a behavior similar to v1 functions where I can reliably respond to document creation. Thanks for pointing out that more clarity was needed! All of the v2 functionality you've listed is what has our interest. :-) 

I see beta/preview clarifiers for Eventarc + Cloud Run (or others) at https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/creating-triggers, but no mention of the event sources in this question (Firestore). Thanks!

Comment: I want to clarify that we want the behavior of Firestore triggers, but using Eventarc that v2 requires. Per https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore ("Cloud Functions (2nd gen) does not currently support Cloud Firestore triggers.")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore (as recent as Sept 7, 2022):

> Cloud Functions (2nd gen) does not currently support Cloud Firestore triggers.

From https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling (as recent as Sept 7, 2022):

> Note: Eventarc does not currently support direct events from Firestore, Google Analytics for Firebase, or Firebase Authentication. Use Cloud Functions (1st gen) to use these events.

If you want the v1 behavior with Eventarc, it's not currently supported. Continue to use v1 functions.